# How do you copy just the visible text from the folded state in an org-mode buffer?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

How to copy org file to other buffer, if source is:

```
** TODO task #1
   - some text for task #1
** TODO task #2 
   - some text for task #2
```

but when you collapse all tasks it will look like

```
** TODO task #1 ...
** TODO task #2 ...
```

I want to mark all tasks and copy to another buffer and it must look like a second variant. Don't include texts for tasks which stored inside every task. 
How i can to do it ?

Comment: I think an actual example showing the before and after states would be helpful. With your current description I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve. Make sure you use Stack Overflow's "markdown" syntax to format the example text, otherwise you'll get lines running into each other (as has happened above).

Comment: I think the question is "How do you copy just the visible text from the folded state in an org-mode buffer?"

Comment: `org-mode` is derived from `outline-mode`, so it looks like `outline-headers-as-kill` ought to be relevant, but that doesn't actually seem to work. It seemed worth mentioning, though -- maybe there's a relatively simple fix?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As per Hendy's comment, in current versions of org-mode you use `org-copy-visible` (`C-c C-x v`) to copy the visible content of the current region to the kill ring. (`C-x h` can be used first to mark the entire buffer, as usual.)

In addition, note that the export dispatch menu (`C-x C-e`) provides a "Visible only" switch, if you want to export that content to a different format.

For older versions of org-mode, the original answer below should still apply:

---

`M-x org-export-visible RET SPC` will copy only the currently-visible text of your org-mode buffer into a new buffer.

> org-export-visible is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `org-exp.el'.
>
> (org-export-visible TYPE ARG)
>
> Create a copy of the visible part of the current buffer, and export it.
>   The copy is created in a temporary buffer and removed after use.
>   TYPE is the final key (as a string) that also select the export command in
>   the `C-c C-e' export dispatcher.
>   As a special case, if the you type SPC at the prompt, the temporary
>   org-mode file will not be removed but presented to you so that you can
>   continue to use it.  The prefix arg ARG is passed through to the exporting
>   command.

If you wanted to bind that (to `C-c o` in this example), you could use the following:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'my-org-mode-hook)
(defun my-org-mode-hook ()
  "Custom behaviours when entering org-mode."
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-c o") (function (lambda () (interactive)
                                           (org-export-visible ?\s nil)))))
```

Comment: FYI: this is now done with `C-c C-x v` per the [orgmode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Visibility-cycling.html)

Comment: This answer is great and it is sad that I already upvoted it two years ago, cause I wanna upvote it again today.

Comment: Thanks @NikanaReklawyks :)  I've found myself in the same situation before.  There was even one occasion where I was unable to up-vote the answer which solved my problem because it turned out to have been written by me :)

Comment: This is super useful, thanks! For future incoming google searches: this also works for "folded" links ("descriptive links"). So if you want to copy links without the [[...]] stuff, just the title, you can set the links to "descriptive", select, and copy. Useful for sharing org text containing links.

Answer (score 11):

There is `org-copy-visible`, that should do exactly what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try `M-x org-todo-list` (or <kbd>C-c a t</kbd>). This brings up a list of **TODO** entries (in the files listed in agenda file list) in the *Org Agenda* buffer.

You may need to add your current file to the agenda file list. From `org-agenda` documentation:

> If the current buffer is in Org-mode and visiting a file, you can also
>   first press '<' once to indicate that the agenda should be temporarily
>   (until the next use of C-c a) restricted to the current file.
>   Pressing '<' twice means to restrict to the current subtree or region
>   (if active).