# Copying (yanking) only visible text in emacs outline-mode

Tags: emacs

Sometimes I'd like to copy only the visible text from an outline-mode buffer in emacs, ignoring hidden leaves, etc.

I don't see any way to do this. When I use M-w and then paste somewhere else, I get all the text, including the hidden parts.

Does anyone know how to do this? The manual and google aren't helping.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Update in 2021: `org-copy-visible` works without any modifications, and does regions too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Edit:* Tom Faulhaber's solution, as per the comment below:
https://gist.github.com/tomfaulhaber/519635

*Original answer:*

FWIW, org-mode has [org-export-visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193985/how-do-you-copy-just-the-visible-text-from-the-folded-state-in-an-org-mode-buffer/3212700#3212700), and is derived from outline-mode, so maybe that code could be adapted if no other solution exists?

There's also `M-x outline-headers-as-kill` which works on the region in outline-minor-mode. That's also not what you wanted, but perhaps provides another approach for implementation.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I simplified org-export-visible to create outline-yank-visible. The code is here http://gist.github.com/519635 if anyone needs it.

Comment: Nice one. That function copies rather than yanks, though... maybe `outline-copy-visible` would be a better name?

Comment: Good point, I don't know quite what I was thinking with the name. I changed it as you suggest in the gist.

Comment: @TomFaulhaber Perhaps it would be a good idea to convert your great comment into an answer. For me I almost overlooked the answer in your comment!

Comment: @TomFaulhaber Awesome. But is it possible to adjust it so that it copies only the selected region?

Comment: Update in 2021: `org-copy-visible` works without any modifications, and does regions too!